# Integers $d$ for which the Negative Pell equation is soluble for both $d$ and $2d$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, pell-type-equations

Let $\text{NPE}_d$ denote the negative Pell equation:
$$ x^2-dy^2=-1$$
Where $d$ is a given positive nonsquare integer and integer solutions are sought for x and y.

we know that ([in this paper](http://www.numbertheory.org/pdfs/negative_pell.pdf)):

> **Theorem :** The equation $\text{NPE}_d$ has integer solutions if and only if there exist two integers $a(d)=a$ and $b(d)=b$ such that $d=a^2+b^2$ and there exists a Pythagorean triplet $(A,B,C)$
>   such that $|aA-bB|=1$ and in this case $(Aa+Bb,C)$ is a solution.

Obviously if $\text{NPE}_d$ has integer solutions then $d$ cannot be divisible by any prime $p$ such that $p=3\mod 4$.

> My **question**: Is there any characterization for the integers $d$ for which $\text{NPE}_d$ and $\text{NPE}_{2d}$ have both integer solutions.

I used the characterization above, but I can't link the couple $(a(d),b(d))$ 
to $(a(2d),b(2d))$ because the theorem doesn't give us much information

The sequence  of the elements $d$ for which $\text{NPE}_d$  is soluble is OEIS [A031396](http://oeis.org/A031396).

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Now posted to MO, http://mathoverflow.net/questions/202735/integers-d-for-which-the-negative-pell-equation-is-soluble-for-both-d-and-2

Answer (score -1):

It is necessary to use the formula.    http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/blog/101140

$$x^2-dy^2=-1$$

$$z^2-2dg^2=-1$$

It will give us a series of solutions using the Pell equation:  $$p^2-2s^2=k$$

Let us use the fact that the following solution can be found knowing the previous, formula.

$$p_2=3p_1+4s_1$$

$$s_2=2p_1+3s_1$$

Using certain series of solutions you can find ratio formula.

$p^2-2s^2=1$     $;$     $(p_1;s_1) - (3;2);$  $d=s^2+1$

$p^2-2s^2=-1$   $;$   $(p_1;s_1) - (1;1) ;$   $d=s^2+4$

$p^2-2s^2=-7$    $;$   $(p_1;s_1)  - (1;2) ;$    $d=s^2+1$

$p^2-2s^2=7$    $;$   $(p_1;s_1) - (3;1) ;$   $d=s^2+4$

$p^2-2s^2=17$   $;$   $(p_1 ; s_1)  - (5;2) ;$  $d=s^2+9$

While it is difficult to say. Limited to any solution of these series or not.  Clearly what is involved in this equation Pell.

Comment: which formula I have to use in your link? is this an answer? if yes: what is your conclusion about the characterization of the integers $d$ for which the two equations have solutions? thanks

Comment: @Elaqqad  You don't understand the meaning of the formulas on the link and those who drew?

Comment: yes I didn't find any connexion between my question and the link,I think that I need more explications, thinks.